# How to search two fields in document using nodejs(express) mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have created ArticleSchema. Following is my dummy data from which i want to find the articles based on some fields.

```
$scope.Articles = [{
      email: "vijaybs@gmail.com",
      Type: "Magazine",
      Storename: "Vijay Book stores",
      Categories:"Business Today,Intelligent Computing CHIP magazine,Electronics For You"

    }, {

      email: "news.martin@gmail.com",
      Type: "Newspaper",
      Storename: "Martin morning news",
      Categories:"The Deccan Times,"


    }, {

      email: "vinay@gmail.com",
      Type: "Newspaper,Magazine",
      Storename: "google news center",
      Categories:"Electronics For You,Business Today,Business Line,Calicut Review,The Financial Express"


    }, {

      email: "hotnews@gmail.com",
      Type: "Newspaper",
      Storename: "Hot news center",
      Categories:"The Hindu,The Deccan Times,Business Line,Business Today"



    }]
```

I want to filter the data by  categories and type field.

controller

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    errorHandler = require('./errors.server.controller'),
    Article = mongoose.model('Article'),
    _ = require('lodash');

/**
 * Create a article
 */
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var article = new Article(req.body);
    article.user = req.user;

    article.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(article);
        }
    });
};

/**
 * Show the current article
 */
exports.read = function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.article);
};

/**
 * Update a article
 */
exports.update = function(req, res) {
    var article = req.article;

    article = _.extend(article, req.body);

    article.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(article);
        }
    });
};

/**
 * Delete an article
 */
exports.delete = function(req, res) {
    var article = req.article;

    article.remove(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(article);
        }
    });
};

/**
 * List of Articles
 */
exports.list = function(req, res) {
    Article.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, articles) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(articles);
        }
    });
};

/**
 * Article middleware
 */
exports.articleByID = function(req, res, next, id) {
    Article.findById(id).populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, article) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!article) return next(new Error('Failed to load article ' + id));
        req.article = article;
        next();
    });
};
```

model

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/**
 * Article Schema
 */
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({

    email: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,

    },
    Storename: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    Type: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    Categories: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }


});

mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
```

What is the query to filter the given data in mongoose

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code and pass the type and categories in the request.

routes.js

```
 app.route('/articles/filter')

      .post(articles.getArticles);
```

Controller.js

```
 exports.getArticles = function(req, res) {
Article.find({Type:{'$regex':'Magazine'},Categories:{'$regex':'Business Today'}}).exec(function(err, articles) {
 if (err) {
  return res.status(400).send({ message:  errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err) }); 
} 
else { console.log(articles);res.json(articles); } 
}); 
};
```

Comment: if you don't mind i need one help from your side @Mariya James

Comment: i am using meanjs for backend and front end i am using diffrent server when ever i create article i am getting  req.isAuthenticated is showing fail .what should i pass for this pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842707/mean-js-req-isauthenticated-is-showing-fail

Comment: your code not working it's passing empty .i have passed like this var details={
        
"type":'Magazine',
"Categories":'Business Today'
}
$http.post('http://****/articles/' +details).success(function(data, response) 
{
 console.log(data);
});

Comment: no it's not working it's passing only[] like this .i have passed type:Magazine,Categories:Business Today it's not working dude

Comment: { type: [ 'Magazine' ],
  Categories: [ 'Business Today' ] }

Comment: Article.find({Type:'Magazine',Categories:'Business Today'}).sort('-created').exec(function(err, articles) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        res.json(articles);console.log(articles);
    }
});
};//i have tried like this in console i am getting empty[]

Comment: can you pls help me out

Comment: if i put i am getting all data

Comment: Article.find({Type:'Magazine',Categories:{$regex': 'Business Today''}}).exec(function(err, articles) { if (err) { return res.status(400).send({ message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err) }); } else { console.log(articles); res.json(articles);} });   try this it will work

Comment: getting error Article.find({Type:'Magazine',Categories:{$regex': 'Business Today''}
                                         ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)

Comment: why it's not passing any idea?